# What is causing "Not unique table/alias" error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql query below.

```
UPDATE data_records
  INNER JOIN doors
  ON (sensors.gateway_id = doors.id)
  INNER JOIN data_records
  ON (data_records.sensor_id = sensors.id)
SET data_records.value=1
WHERE doors.addr='FFA'
```

I am at a loss what caused the error `Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Not unique table/alias: 'data_records'`. I clearly have data_records table in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not join  sensors but two time data_recods

```
UPDATE data_records
INNER JOIN doors   ON (sensors.gateway_id = doors.id)
INNER JOIN sensors ON (data_records.sensor_id = sensors.id)
SET data_records.value=1
WHERE doors.addr='FFA'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two joins to `data_records`.  I think you intend:

```
UPDATE data_records dr INNER JOIN
       sensors s
       ON dr.sensor_id = s.id INNER JOIN
       doors d
       ON s.gateway_id = d.id
    SET dr.value = 1
WHERE d.addr = 'FFA';
```

Your query references `sensors` but does not define it in the `UPDATE` clause.

Also note that I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

You either did a mistake, and used `data_records` twice instead of `sensors` table, or you just meant to alias the second `data_records` as `sensors` . Either way this is wrong .

First option:

```
UPDATE data_records
  INNER JOIN doors
  ON (sensors.gateway_id = doors.id)
  INNER JOIN sensors
  ON (data_records.sensor_id = sensors.id)
SET data_records.value=1
WHERE doors.addr='FFA'
```

Second one:

```
UPDATE data_records
  INNER JOIN doors
  ON (sensors.gateway_id = doors.id)
  INNER JOIN data_records sensors
  ON (data_records.sensor_id = sensors.id)
SET data_records.value=1
WHERE doors.addr='FFA'
```